# Can you create a SQL Update statement in Matillion?

Tags: matillion

I'm trying to create an UPDATE statement in the SQL component in Matillion however I get a syntax error at SET.

```
UPDATE matchingmanufacturernofulllast2
SET "matchingmanufacturernofulllast2.available" = 'f'
where listprice is not null 



ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"
  Position: 88
```

Does Matillion sql component have the ability to use the sql UPDATE syntax?

Regards
Conteh

Comment: What's the underlying DB this statement is aimed at?

Comment: @ericHauenstein it's aimed at redshift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SQL *orchestration* component for DDL. The SQL *transformation* component is for Select only.

https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2107012

Answer (score 0):

One option to create an update statement with a where clause in Matillion is to use the [calculator component](https://snowflake-support.matillion.com/s/article/1991925) in conjuction with a [case expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html)

```
CASE
WHEN ("listprice" is not null)
THEN 'F'
END
```